# Can Thaumcraft 4 be played as a team?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods, minecraft-mods, minecraft-thaumcraft

My wife and I have started playing through the [Regrowth modpack](http://www.feed-the-beast.com/modpacks/Regrowth).
We are set as a party in the [Hardcore Questing Mode](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/1294538-hardcore-questing-mode-party-hard-3-2-0) book, and it is just the two of us on the server (running locally via "Open to LAN").

We have been having great fun working together.

The Regrowth modpack eventually will work its way around to Thaumcraft.
It has the following mods of relevance:

- Thaumcraft
- Thaumcraft NEI Plugin
- Thaumcraft Node Tracker
- Thaumic Exploration

It does not have Thaumic Tinker, which IIRC has some items regarding multiplaying thaumcraft, though I have never really looked at them before. (I'm not entirely adverse to adding Thaumic Tinker to the modpack if it would solve the issues.)

- **Is it possible to work together on Thaumcraft?**
- Can you share unlocked recipes?

  - by just using the same Thaumnomicon?
- Can you share Aspects?

Comment: You cannot share aspects, but with below mentioned recipe duplication, you can switch who uses aspects to unlock new recipes. However "click to buy" recipes everybody has to buy on their own. Also for casting spells (like starting the altar) you have to have such a recipe unlocked in your book, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: @AntoineHejlík Sounds like the start of a solid answer, why not make it one?

Answer (score 3):

While Thaumic Tinker does provide the big book of knowledge for unlocking other people's research, basic Thaumcraft 4.0 does have the ability to duplicate a completed but unlearned research notes.

The quote from the [Wikia Wiki](http://thaumcraft-4.wikia.com/wiki/Research_Mastery#Meta-Research) that pertains is pasted here:

> Research Duplication: Allows you to duplicate a completed research note, but 
>       only before learning it yourself. This is meant for multi-player games, but 
>       note that it is still available in single-player -- and there is a point in 
>       the late game where you need to have completed all available research, to 
>       get the next topic. In multi-player, it's primarily useful for carrying 
>       another player "on your back", for example a friend who is having trouble 
>       with the minigame. It requires Research Mastery.

All Thaumnomicons are the same, they just show you your progress so that will not help in this regard. Additionally there is currently no way to share Aspects directly. Their only real use is to be used in research however so as long as you are careful not to research the same things and duplicate everything properly, you can in essence get double aspects from everything if you both can them and apply them to different recipes.